# Find fitting distribution for chi^2 goodness-of-fit test in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, statistical-test, goodness-of-fit

I am struggling with finding a fitting distribution for a chi square goodness-of-fit test in R. My quantile is 66.77, but my test statistic is staying far apart from it. The best distribution I found is an exponential distribution with parameter 0.143, whereby my test statistic has a value of 109.11. I also tried an erlang distribution, but no parameters were better than exponential parameters. Which distributions could also work, and which formulas do I have to use to calculate the expected frequencies for them?
I also tried to use the provided chi square test in R, but I get very different test statistics compared to the test statistics I calculated with a for loop by the sum of (observedValue - expectedValue)^2/expectedValue.

[Expected observations for Exp(0.143)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8C4t.png)

Comment: This is really a statistical question rather than a programming question.